# Should I avoid catching database exceptions in a servlet?

Tags: java, exception, servlets

I read about [throw early catch late](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late) principle and now I'm wondering whether or not should I catch database exception in my servlets.

In my opinion, servlet is the final point in my application where I can make decision about program flow. I can send http error code back to the client while doing this at dao layer seems strange to me.

If I'm wrong I'll be glad to hear how to properly catch database exception in dao layer.

Comment: Hav  you tried it? It won't even compile.

Comment: @EJP For what reason it won't compile? Suppose I'm in a doPost() method and I write
            userService.save(new User());

I can catch it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Throw early catch late` is not a solution for expected failures which raise exceptions.

When writing networking code, it is common for the network to drop packets, or for services you are attempting to use to be unreachable.  Causing the entire servlet to crash would be a very poor practice because it would require the network to be operational for the servlet to be operational.

This doesn't seem like a good user experience, and a more reasonable approach would be to present that you are attempting to connect to the database, and failing, and reattempting, and failing, etc.  At least with that kind of output, you get a better complaint that the database is unavailable, instead of your servlet is crashing.

Comment: Note that in general, "throw early catch late" is a great idea.  It's just not a great idea for non-exceptional events that just happen to raise exceptions because such common events should not interrupt the entire program's flow of execution.

Comment: nice explanation + 1, but can you also provide some links to read it further.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal https://stripe.com/blog/idempotency touches on a lot of the ideas of making something safe to retry, if you intend to make a retry-able command.  If you want a retry-able data read, you just attempt to connect again and re-read the data.